Some blogs on probability and mathematical statistics
What are some of the blogs one can look up to for knowing more on probability and statistical theory and problems ?(similar to like terry tao or Tim towers blogs for mathematics )

I am closing this question because it is off-topic, per the guidelines in the Help Center.  In particular, this is a question for which "every answer is equally valid".  It is also not clear how this is connected with mathematics education, in the sense that this is a site for math educators to give advice to other math educators (not for math educators to give advice to math learners).

I like the blog of Andrew Gelman (stats prof at Columbia):
https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/
Pretty topical posts.  Not hard core theory, more practical.  But they vary.

I stan Cosma Shalizi pretty hard as well:  http://bactra.org/weblog/
